# Get programmatically cc:interface definition

Tags: jsf, interface, composite-component

In this example:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" required="false" />
    <composite:editableValueHolder name="txtText"/>
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <h:inputText id="txtText" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
</composite:implementation>
```

I'd like to retrieve what have been set to `editableValueHolder` as I would do for attributes (e.g `component.getAttributes().get("value")`), but I didn't find method to do so

Comment: Retrieve these information from `component` itself, I'd imagine something like `component.getInterfaces().get('editableValueHolder')`. The aim of this is to know which EditableValueHolder my composite targets

Comment: Not retrieve what, retrieve **where**, in a bean, component class, in the component xhtml

Comment: Retrieve from a component class

Comment: I never needed to use a construction like this (yet), so I'm thinking of a usecase. The 'target's (implicit identical to name)is fixed (name is fixed), so you can already know what input is targeted. Can you describe the real functional usecase for which you are trying to solve this in the way you ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is stored in *composite component BeanInfo* which is available as composite component attribute keyed by [`UIComponent.BEANINFO_KEY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#BEANINFO_KEY).

> `public static final String BEANINFO_KEY`
>
> The value of this constant is used as the key in the component attribute map, the value for which is a [`java.beans.BeanInfo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) implementation describing the composite component. This `BeanInfo` is known as the *composite component BeanInfo*.

The `<cc:editableValueHolder>` creates a [`EditableValueHolderAttachedObjectTarget`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/EditableValueHolderAttachedObjectTarget.html) instance in the [`List<AttachedObjectTarget>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/AttachedObjectTarget.html) property of the *composite component BeanInfo* which is available by the key [`AttachedObjectTarget.ATTACHED_OBJECT_TARGETS_KEY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/AttachedObjectTarget.html#ATTACHED_OBJECT_TARGETS_KEY).

> `static final String ATTACHED_OBJECT_TARGETS_KEY`
>
> The key in the value set of the *composite component BeanDescriptor*, the value for which is a `List<AttachedObjectTarget>`.

All in all, this should do in order to get the `txtText`:

```
<cc:interface componentType="yourComposite">
    ...
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="txtText" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <f:event type="postAddToView" listener="#{cc.init}" />
    <h:inputText id="txtText" ... />
    ...
</cc:implementation>
```

```
@FacesComponent("yourComposite")
public class YourComposite extends UINamingContainer {

    public void init() {
        BeanInfo info = (BeanInfo) getAttributes().get(UIComponent.BEANINFO_KEY);
        List<AttachedObjectTarget> targets = (List<AttachedObjectTarget>) info.getBeanDescriptor().getValue(AttachedObjectTarget.ATTACHED_OBJECT_TARGETS_KEY);

        for (AttachedObjectTarget target : targets) {
            if (target instanceof EditableValueHolderAttachedObjectTarget) {
                String name = target.getName();
                UIInput txtText = (UIInput) findComponent(name);
                // ...
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Said that, this all is unnecessarily clumsy. Much simpler and the [more canonical  approach](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aa%20facescomponent%20componenttype%20binding) is to just bind the child component directly to the backing component.

```
<cc:interface componentType="yourComposite">
    ...
    <cc:editableValueHolder name="txtText" />
</cc:interface>
<cc:implementation>
    <h:inputText binding="#{cc.txtText}" ... />
    ...
</cc:implementation>
```

```
@FacesComponent("yourComposite")
public class YourComposite extends UINamingContainer {

    private UIInput txtText; // +getter+setter

    // ...
}
```

Comment: The 'none-clumsy' way was what I was thinking about to, the first part I would never have found out.

Comment: Thanks BalusC once again! ;)

Answer (score -2):

You can get what you want through the managedBean.

A simple POJO :

```
public class MyObject{

private String attribute;
private String editableValueHolder ;

//getter and setter
//...
}
```

Your ManagedBean :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class myManagedBean{

private MyObject selected;

//getter and setter
//...
}
```

Your web page :

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:myLib="http://lib.dz/taglib">

<h:form>

<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputText value="Attribute" />
    <h:inputText value="#{myManagedBean.attribute}" />
    <h:outputText value="EditableValueHolder " />
    <h:inputText value="#{myManagedBean.editableValueHolder }" />
</h:panelGrid>

</h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: :-)... unfortunately it is not that simple. The concepts used in the question are core jsf things, not just bean properties